# SQL syntax error with UPDATE ... FROM ... JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm learning SQL and have built up a little database so far. Now I have 2 tables called `countries_visited` and `regions_visited` with the following schema,

`countries_visited`: [`id`,`countries`,`year_visited`]

`regions_visited`: [`r_id`,`regions`,`c_id`,`month_visited`]

The `id` column in `countries_visited` is a primary key, and the `c_id` column of `regions_visited` is a foreign key linked to `countries_visited`

The `month_visited` column in `regions_visited` is newly created and all entries are now `NULL`. What I want to do is to individually insert the entry into this new column with conditions.

So, I tried the following statement taking from the earlier examples here in StackOverflow,

```
UPDATE regions_visited
SET month_visited = 9
FROM countries_visited 
JOIN regions_visited ON countries_visited.id = regions_visited.c_id
WHERE regions_visited.regions = 'Seoul' 
AND countries_visited.year_visited = 2006
AND countries_visited.countries = 'South Korea';
```

By running this command on MySQL server, it shows this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'FROM regions_visited INNER JOIN countries_visited
>   ON regions_visited.c_id = coun' at line 1

However, if neglecting the `UPDATE` and `SET` part of the statement, mysql shows the joined table with only 1 row that I would like to update. What did I do wrong? How to make this work?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: mysql UPDATE does not support "FROM" - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, the `join` clauses come before the `set`clause:

```
UPDATE regions_visited rv
JOIN   countries_visited cv ON  ON cv.id = rv.c_id
SET    month_visited = 9
WHERE  rv.regions = 'Seoul' AND 
       cv.year_visited = 2006 AND
       cv.countries = 'South Korea';
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `Join` before `SET`. Try this

```
UPDATE regions_visited 
       JOIN regions_visited 
         ON countries_visited.id = regions_visited.c_id 
SET    month_visited = 9 
WHERE  regions_visited.regions = 'Seoul' 
       AND countries_visited.year_visited = 2006 
       AND countries_visited.countries = 'South Korea';
```

Comment: I wonder how many other countries have regions called 'Seoul'?